# What is the effective way of setting up delete event listener using event delegation with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to set up a delete event listener with event delegation. Here is the snippet.

```js
document.getElementById('container').addEventListener('click', deleteProfile);


function deleteProfile(event){

    //console.log(event.target);
    
    const profileId = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id;
    
    if(profileId === 'profile-0')
    {
        //Delete the profile
        console.log('profile deleted');
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="container">
 <div id="profile-0">
    <div id="heading">
       <h3>Profile Tim</h3>
    </div>

    <div id="body">
       <div id="profileInfo_details">
          <figure>
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140">
          </figure>
          <label for="name">Name: </label>
          <p id="name">Tim<p>
          <label for="location">Location: </label>
          <p id="location">Boston<p>

          <button id="delete_profile" type="button">
             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Delete profile
          </button>
       </div>

       <div id="footer">
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Given the fact that the image element inside the figure element is at the same DOM level as the button to delete the stuff, I get the message: `"deleted profile"` whenever I click on the image. How can I only get the message when I click on the `button` or `span` element?

Comment: Check what was clicked

Comment: `const profileId = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id;`, you really should use `closest()`

Comment: how can i use closest() in this situation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, look to see if what is clicked is the button. This really needs a class on it if there are more than one button in the element.

```js
document.getElementById('container').addEventListener('click', deleteProfile);


function deleteProfile(event){
  var button = event.target.closest("button");
  if (button) {
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log('button')
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="container">
 <div id="profile-0">
    <div id="heading">
       <h3>Profile Tim</h3>
    </div>

    <div id="body">
       <div id="profileInfo_details">
          <figure>
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140">
          </figure>
          <label for="name">Name: </label>
          <p id="name">Tim<p>
          <label for="location">Location: </label>
          <p id="location">Boston<p>

          <button id="delete_profile" type="button">
             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Delete profile
          </button>
       </div>

       <div id="footer">
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're attaching your event listener to the wrong DOM element. Attach it to the button with id `delete_profile` and you will only get the console message when the button or any of it's child elements are clicked. Try this snippet:

```js
document.getElementById('delete_profile').addEventListener('click', deleteProfile);


function deleteProfile(event){

    //console.log(event.target);
    
    const profileId = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id;
    
    if(profileId === 'profile-0')
    {
        //Delete the profile
        console.log('profile deleted');
    
    }


}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="container">
 <div id="profile-0">
    <div id="heading">
       <h3>Profile Tim</h3>
    </div>

    <div id="body">
       <div id="profileInfo_details">
          <figure>
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140">
          </figure>
          <label for="name">Name: </label>
          <p id="name">Tim<p>
          <label for="location">Location: </label>
          <p id="location">Boston<p>

          <button id="delete_profile" type="button">
             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Delete profile
          </button>
       </div>

       <div id="footer">
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't want to attach to the button because multiple same buttons with same DOM structure on the list items